# Display Debug output in a clean format Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to display the message output of a debug command in a nice format in Ansible. At the moment this is how the output looks:

```
TASK [stop : Report Status of Jenkins Process] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Service Jenkins is Running.\nReturn code from `grep`:\n0\n"
}

TASK [stop : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "Service Jenkins is Running.\nReturn code from `grep`:\n0\n"
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of the '\n' character and replace with a new line?
The code below using the `split('\n')` does not work.

```
- name: Checking Jenkins Process
  shell: "ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -v dhclient | grep jenkins"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: jenkins_process

- debug:
    var: jenkins_process.rc

- name: Report Status of Jenkins Process
  fail:
    msg: |
      Service Jenkins is not found
      Return code from `grep`:
      {{ jenkins_process.rc }}
  when: jenkins_process.rc != 0
  register: report

- name: Report Status of Jenkins Process
  debug:
    msg: |
      Service Jenkins is Running.
      Return code from `grep`:
      {{ jenkins_process.rc }}
  when: jenkins_process.rc == 0
  register: report

- debug:
    msg: "{{ report.split('\n') }}"

- name: Stop Jenkins Service
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: stopped
```

Is there a way to display this in a nice way?

Comment: see also https://serverfault.com/questions/640130/display-output-with-ansible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/debug.html) callback plugin.

You can specify it on command line:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug ansible-playbook ...
```

Or in your `default` section of your `ansible.cfg` configuration file:

```
stdout_callback = debug
```