# Removing escape characters and format Ansible debug output

Tags: ansible, format

Is there any way to sort this Ansible output?

I tried to use regex but still displaying escape character and display the output in the following format.

```json
 - "Description": "\nRequested for Details:\n\nRequested for Name: Maddy
   XYZ\nRequested for Email: abc.def@ghi.com\nRequested for Number:
   12345678\nRequested for Phone: \nRequested for Department:
   EDUCATION\nRequested for User Domain:\n\nRequested by
   Details:\nRequested by Name: Maddy XYZ\nRequested by Email:
   abc.def@ghi.com\\nRequested by Employee Number: 12345678\nRequested
   by Phone: \n\nRequest Details: \nItem: ABC OPERATIONS - Request
   Form\nCode: Services\Code: M1N0\nEnvironment: no\nDescription: 1.
   Result is coming as not pass for every application\n2. additional
   description\nPriority: High\nRequest and Response (XMLs, JSON):
   result is not
   pass\n{\"\":\"NOTFOOUND\",\"\":\"FULL\",\"AlertsEvalResult\":\"FULL\",\"identityAlertsEvalResult\":\"FULL\",\"\":{\"RptScore\":1000,\"numInq\":0,\"RptSourceType\":\"Intrnl\",\"RptMessages\":[{\"seqNum\":0,\"message\":\"No
   File
   (L2)\"}],\"Alerts\":null,\"\":null,\"identityAlerts\":null,\"internalAlerts\":[{\"code\":\"500\",\"description\":\"No
   File\",
```

How I can display this output in standard format?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape backslash and double quote in Ansible (script module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580797/how-to-escape-backslash-and-double-quote-in-ansible-script-module)

Comment: What do you expect? Please don't answer in comments, edit your question. While you're at it, format your pasted output correctly in a code block. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question that you like to display the `ansible-playbook` output in an other way formatted.

Whereby with a default setting in `ansible.cfg` of

```
# stdout_callback         = yaml
```

a playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    text: |

      This is:
      Some longer example text

      with line breaks.

  tasks:

  - name: Show message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ text }}"
```

results into an output of

```json
TASK [Show message] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "\nThis is:\nSome longer example text\n\nwith line breaks.\n"
}
```

[Setting an other callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#setting-a-callback-plugin-for-ansible-playbook)

```
stdout_callback         = yaml
```

will result into an [yaml-ized Ansible screen output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/yaml_callback.html) output of

```yaml
TASK [Show message] ********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |2-

    This is:
    Some longer example text

    with line breaks.
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Index of all Callback Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_callback.html)

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible `stdout` Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017860/6771046)
- [Display `ansible-playbook` output properly formatted](https://serverfault.com/questions/1031491/)
- [Display `debug` output in a clean format Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54943100/6771046)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I defined it in ansible.cfg but was not getting applied. later I passed the ansible config from commandl line and it worked :D Thanks.